# SSRS 2012 - Custom Authentication - The permissions granted to user " are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2012

Whenever I want to deploy a report in Visual Studio I receive the error message

> The permissons grated to user " are insufficient for performing this
>   operation".

I am using custom authentication (with a form) on the Report Server / Manager and the Login via the Webpage works fine. Further, I also added an administrator role to the Report Manager. In Visual Studio I then changed the credentials in the Shared Data Source from Windows Authentication to "Use this user name and password" and specified the administrator name. However, I still receive the same error message and the user " part of the error seems to indicate that Visual Studio tries to connect with an empty user name.

Can you please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/40221010/2198089> for same issue checkout my answer here, it may help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an override for the authorization portion. It may be that you are authenticating the user, however, SSRS needs to know if the authenticated user can update report definitions by given authorization. If you are using custom security then you should look adding authorization for the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please get a bit more specific what to do here? As far as I understand custom authentication, there are different checkAccess methods for various operations in the Authorization.cs file. What I did for a test, is to set a return true directly after the header of each method. However, now it gives me the following error in Visual Studio when I deploy the report: "An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database". Any ideas on that?

Comment: Overriding all authorization methods to return true should give the authenticated user access to deploy reports. It sounds like you have got past that but hit another snag. From what you stated it seems there is a problem when you are connecting to the SSRS database during deployment. I would start by checking the connection settings you are using for deployment and determine if you can access that server/database from your development machine.

Comment: I think we are getting pretty close to a solution. In the log file, I found a more detailed error description: "Procedure or function "SetAllProperties" expects parameter '@ModifiedByName', which was not supplied." However, there is no such parameter in my Report. My initial idea was, that this error takes us back to the initial question, that the user parameter is empty ("") whenever I deploy the report in Visual Studio. Does anyone have some ideas how to fix this or does anyone have some other ideas for the source of this error?

Comment: I don't think SetAllProperties is a SSRS function. How are you calling it?

Comment: I think I am not calling the function directly / intentionally. I found one more post on the internet with this problem, but there was no solution provided yet. The SetAllProperties function is an internal function and is thrown by: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException / System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException. My initial ideas was, that whenever a report is deployed, there is an internal property @ModifiedByName which is set by the SetAllProperties function, so it is created whenever a report is deployed to the server by the ReportingServices class

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, This issue was in my web.config (located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer) I had the below configuration for Report Service asmx file. When I commented the below lines every thing was normal. I was able to see the login dialog prompting for the user name and password.

```
<location path="ReportService2010.asmx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Hope this help someone else. More details can be found on this blog
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2005/11/29/497848.aspx