# SSRS permissions granted to user domain/computer$

Tags: asp.net, security, reporting-services

I have been through all the link here and many are old. I have goggled and tried the hacks and nothing has worked. The reporting server and web server are different servers. I have created an ASP.NET app as a wrapper to view `SSRS` reports. I want to select various parameters and pass to `SSRS`. Tested on development machine and all is working. Have created a site for this ASP page on the web server (IIS 7.5). When I launch the site I get the error: The permissions granted to user `DOMAINNAME\WEBSERVER$` are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)  . I have addeds this user to the roles with full authority both in site settings and at the report folder level in report managager and also in the security of the site and I still get this error. I am aware that I could simply use an iframe and a URl to the report server, but `HTML5` has issues with iframes and I cant get rid of the scroll bars on the silly iframe. I hope someone knows of a way to use the report viewer control in `ASP.NET`.

Comment: You tried everything in the related links?  This one is very thorough and contains everything I would suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132812/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation?rq=1

Comment: Why is this so difficult? I saw your link before and thought I had tried everything, but, what finally worked was changing the identity in Application Pools of the site to the domain administrator.

Comment: Good job.  I'm sure that you won't just leave it running under a domain admin account (too risky).  Now that you know it is a permission issue, you can create a utility account (for this to run-as) and narrow-down/tune-in the permissions.  Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapped report requires user privileges based on the Windows Authentication but you run it under the ASPNET account. All you have to do is to enable impersonation. To do this insert the following line into the web.config file:

```
<!-- Web.config file. --/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

More help could be found here: [Using the WebForms ReportViewer Control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx)