# The permissions granted to user are insufficient for performing this operation while deploying rdl report

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am New To RDL reports.I Construct Report in Businnes Inteligance(BIDS).using sql server 2008 R2.When I Want To Deploy it Generate following Message.

> The permissions granted to user  are insufficient for performing this
>   operation

i search on google found many threads but still i face problem.

followings i implemented.
http://techasp.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-fix-reporting-services.html

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4926d214-e3b3-4337-abfb-fcba179aa662/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation-rsaccessdenied?forum=sqlreportingservices

Please Help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The permissions granted to user ' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)"}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132812/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation)

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed this issue for me.

Connect to Reporting Services via SSMS.  Then open up the security tree then system roles and then opening the properties of System Administrator.   And then added the check boxes to execute the subscription and the issue was gone.   You can fix this in the other roles, i just did it for sys admin.[image]