# ReportViewer errors in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have been trying to get report viewer to work for several days now with no luck.  I have followed several different tutorials but still no dice.

What I am trying to do is create a webform to allow the user to view a remote SRSS report with parameters.  utilizing the following code:

```
protected void ddlTask_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

        ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;

        serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://Server/reportserver");
        serverReport.ReportPath = "/QAQC_Reports/" + sqlCommands.GetSpecificFormReportName(ddlType.SelectedValue);
        ReportParameter BU = new ReportParameter("@BU", ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue);
        ReportParameter TID = new ReportParameter("@TID", ddlTask.SelectedValue);

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new[] { BU, TID });
    }
```

on my aspx page I have the following:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I think I am almost there but I am getting the following error:

The permissions granted to user 'domain\computername$' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132812/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation

Comment: This should work for you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c65abca7-0fdb-40fb-aabe-718f63377a55/set-credentials-for-reportviewer?forum=vsreportcontrols

Comment: @AndreiD this is going on an intranet, is there a way to use the credentials already provided?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the default option actually(been a while since I've done any reports). Are you sure your user has the required permissions set @ http://Server/reports ?

Comment: @AndreiD Well the user popping up in the error looks like my computer name.  I am guessing it's because in debugging my computer is the server?  Do I need to add the server (or my computer) to server/reports?

Comment: Do you have Reporting Services installed on your local machine or are you connecting to an external server? Either way, it's strange that you are getting the computername instead of the username on the rsAccessDenied...Try running as administrator, sometimes Reporting Services behaves strangely when it doesn't have the required permissions.