# IIS 8.5 connecting to remote report services

Tags: iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Here is the scenario:
A web server is running on IIS 8.5 using AppPoolIdendtity to pass through the credential to connect to Reporting Service which is remotely installed in a MSSQL Server.

The reporting service has added the machine account DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$ to the system role assignment from http://MSSSQLRS/ReportServer as System Administrator like this:

[The permissions granted to user ' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132812/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation)

Testing local MSSQL server is smooth with local access. However, whenever the connection is established from the IIS web server. The "rsAccessDenied" error came up as DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$ user.

Not sure what else is wrong either on the WEB IIS or MSSQL server....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like RS Windows NTLM is not configured correctly. See [this](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-reporting-services/understanding-sql-server-reporting-services-authentication) article.

Comment: Turns out I have missed a credential config in my C# app.config. Now it works~