# SSRS 2019 permissions granted to user domain\user are insufficient

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

Reporting Services Error

> The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\user' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help

I had this issue in the past with Windows 10 and the solution was to run it in IE 11 under administrator as per this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/453441/the-permissions-granted-to-user-domainuser-are-ins

As IE 11 is not available anymore I am struggling to get this working.

I tried re-installing my instance of SSRS, re-setting up the WebService URLs, creating a new ReportServer database in SQL Server and configuring the Report Server database credentials in the `Report Server Configuration Manager`. This didn't work.

I also tried going into the `users` and `policyuserrole` tables in the `ReportServer` database and manually added my account and SSRS roles to it. This didn't work.

The Report Manager url doesn't allow me access anything or make security changes.

My account is the only administrator on this machine and is inside the Administrators group.

[image: Administrators Group]

Can anyone help me get this working? Is there something specific to my environment that could be causing this?

Comment: Has the ReportServer database always existed on this particular computer, or has it been restored from a different computer? The `dbo.Users` table contains binary coded SIDs for the groups and users in the domain/workgroup in which it was running. Users from different domains/workgroups will have different SIDs, even when they have the same Username or UPN, and so different sets of permissions will be in effect for them.

Comment: I'm not sure of the database server instance if that what's you meant. I have recreated the ReportServer database from scratch. Interesting thanks, so I used a random SID for the manually inserted records. Where can I find the actual SID of my accounts?

Comment: The commandline tool, `whoami /LOGONID`, will enumerate your current textual SID. You'll have to convert it to a binary SID and use that to update the correct record in the `dbo.Users` table.

Comment: Alternatively, from SSMS, etc., you could get the binary sid via `select SUSER_SID('YourDomain\YouUsername', 1)`, ref: [SUSER_SID (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sid-transact-sql).

Comment: Although Internet Explorer is not available you get still get to the trusted sites options via control panel--> internet options. You should be able to set the trusted sites and then use any browser.

Comment: Ok, I have verified that it is related to my user being from a different domain/workgroup. By adding the site to Trusted Sites, that allowed me to choose a different login from the Administrators group which worked. I'm not sure still how to get my main login working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers given in the comments.

The issue came about due to my computer being part of a work domain with a different user SID.

To get it working for now:

1. Created a local account.
2. Added the site to Trusted Sites in `Internet Options`, the
   browser then prompts for a username and password when accessing the Reports Manager site and it works with the local account.

Answer (score 0):

See the last comment in the article

1. [The permissions granted to user 'Domain\User' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/453441/the-permissions-granted-to-user-domainuser-are-ins)
   or here
2. [Stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132812/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation) or
3. [SSRS : rsAccessDenied : The permissions granted to user are insufficient for performing this operation (rsAccessDenied)](https://sqltimes.wordpress.com/2017/02/18/ssrs-rsaccessdenied-the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation-rsaccessdenied/)

Comment: The OP has said the IE is not available